# Starting from a source, find the next point closest to an objective on a grid in C++

Tags: c++, math

I have an NxN grid with 2 points, the source and destination. I need to move step by step from the source to the destination (which is also moving). How do I determine what the next point is to move to?

One way is to assess all 8 points and see which yields the lowest distance using an Euclidian distance. However, I was hoping there is a cool (mathematical) trick which will yield more elegant results.

Comment: the moving is restricted to the grid points or the grid points serve as approximation for the actual position?

Comment: All _8_ points? So you can move diagonally for the same cost as moving up/down or left/right, even though it's 40% further?

Comment: @tobi303 yes it is restricted to actual grid points.

Comment: @Useless I'm not sure I understand your question. Aren't all 8 points valid for a specific case? In other words, for each of the 8 points there is 1 point which is the closest to the destination.

Comment: In general, you find the full shortest path with BFS. In this specific case, if there are rules which allow you to prove an optimal greedy course, then it becomes possible to determine just the next move. Euclidean distance is obviously not valid in your problem space, so don't use it. Oh, destination is moving ... so you also have to decide if you want to predict where it will be, or just pretend it's not moving?

Comment: Is this the classic "daleks" game?

Comment: @KennyOstrom We pretend it's not moving. Why is Euclidean not valid? I don't need to plot the complete trajectory to the destination. Instead, I need the the point closest to the destination. And yes, I just googled it and it is indeed the daleks game! Didn't know it was called that way!

Comment: Just compare x, compare y, move towards them on both. The dalek always takes the diagonal, although a more optimal strategy might be to try to get on a diagonal forcing the human into the nearest wall. But with just one dalek, I think the human would always die in exactly the same number of moves, for any dalek strategy which involves moving towards the human. (and euclidean distance is not relevant because your moves don't all cover the same distance)

Comment: You're talking about the 8 points surrounding your current position on a 2d grid, right? So, your eight allowed moves are left, right, up, down, left+up, up+right, right+down, down+left. The last 4 move 40% further than the first 4 (distance is `sqrt(2)` instead of 1), which is why I asked if that's allowed. This is why lots of strategy games use hexagonal rather than square grids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question statement allows moving diagonally, which is faster (since it's moving both horizontally *and* vertically in a single step): this solution will always do that unless it has the same x or y coordinate as the target.

```
using Position = pair<int,int>;

Position move(Position const &current, Position const &target) {
    // horizontal and vertical distances
    const int dx = target.first - current.first;
    const int dy = target.second - current.second;
    // horizontal and vertical steps [-1,+1]
    const int sx = dx ? dx/abs(dx) : 0;
    const int sy = dy ? dy/abs(dy) : 0;
    return { current.first + sx, current.second + sy };
}
```

I'm not sure if this counts as a cool mathematical trick though, it just depends on knowing that:

- `dx = target.x-current.x` is positive if you should move in the positive x-direction, negative if you should go in the negative direction, and zero if you should go straight up/down
- `dx/abs(dx)` keeps the sign and removes the magnitude, so it's always one of `-1,0,+1` (avoiding however division by zero)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. In case I want to dumb down the system with prohibiting diagonal movements (to make it easier for the player, it's a game after all), would it be possible with the above?

Comment: Sure, just test which of `abs(dx)` and `abs(dy)` is greater, and zero the other step. If they're the same (and both non-zero), you need to decide which takes precedence.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out! Thank you nevertheless!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that answer to your question is Bresenham's line algorithm. It allows to build sequence of integer points between start and end points in your grid. Anyway you can adapt ideas from it to your problem

For more information see https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html

Answer (score -1):

I would simply use some vector math, take dest minus source as a vector, and then calculate the angle between that vector and some reference vector, e.g. <1, 0>, with standard methods.

Then you can simply divide the circle in 8 (or 4 if your prefer) sections and determine in which section your vector lies from the angle you obtained.

See [euclidean space](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/index.htm) for how to calculate the angle between two vectors.